# Even Parity Checker for 45 bits using 5 IC 74180

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, parity

For a 45 even parity checker, I used 6 X IC 74180 in a cascaded format while making the remaining inputs 0 to design the even parity checker, but is it possible to design it with only 5 X IC 74180 and additional gates?

Comment: Since you are using parallel inputs, few more XOR gates (7486) Would do the trick.

Comment: @LiorBilia I would assume that you want me to use one of the input of each IC as a 2 bit parity checker using XOR ?

Comment: That would be the easiest way, no?